# Date format with Moment.js or classic JS, change places of day and month?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-format, date-formatting

I get date value from my source in this format:
02.08.2016 / Day.Month.Year, it's correct.

but JavaScript understand this inverse, Month.Day.Year.

I tried some ways with Moment.js like:

```
moment('15.08.2016').format('MM.DD.YYYY');
```

My JsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/PAc3j/389/
There are some results visible, see please output, variable dateThree: *Invalid date*

My question is, how can I do it with Moment.js or classic JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want to do just for your machine ? Because on my machine it is perfectly okay as my machine time is month.day.year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the format of the input date string like this.

`moment('15.08.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('MM.DD.YYYY');`

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format

Comment: I'd put that more strongly as "You should **always** specify the input format" since not providing it leaves it up to the parser to guess, which is never a good idea. ;-)